# Collapse Tables with specific Table ID? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have the below JS at the top of my page and it successfully collapses ALL tables on load.
However i am trying to figure out how to only collapse `<table id="ctable">` tables with the ID of "ctable" or is there some other way of specifying the tables to make collapsible etc?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

   var ELpntr=false;
   function hideall()
   {
      locl = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
      for (i=0;i<locl.length;i++)
      {
         locl[i].style.display='none';
      }
   }

   function showHide(EL,PM)
   {
      ELpntr=document.getElementById(EL);
      if (ELpntr.style.display=='none')
      {
         document.getElementById(PM).innerHTML=' - ';
         ELpntr.style.display='block';
      }
      else
      {
         document.getElementById(PM).innerHTML=' + ';
         ELpntr.style.display='none';
      }
   }
   onload=hideall;
</script>
```

HTML echo'd using PHP this is in a for statement looping and there could be multiple tables.

```
echo "<table id=\"ctable\">"
."<thead><tr><th>"
."<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"showHide('show".$show->showid."','span".$show->showid."')\"><span id=\"span".$show->showid."\"><img src=\"images\icon_collapse.gif\"></span><span>".$show->showname."</span></a>"
."</th></tr></thead>";
echo "<table><tbody id=\"show".$show->showid."\">"
."<tr><td rowspan=\"8\"><a class=\"thumbnail\" href=\"#thumb\"><img src=\"".$show->image."\" height=\"150px\" width=\"150px\"><span><img src=\"".$show->image."\"/><br/>".$show->showname."</span></a></td><td rowspan=\"8\"><img class=\"line\" width=\"2\" height=\"100%\"></td><td class=\"jralign\">Show ID:</td><td>".$show->showid."</td></tr>"
."<tr><td class=\"jralign\">Show Link:</td><td><a href=\"".$show->showlink."\">".$show->showlink."</a></td></tr>"
."<tr><td class=\"jralign\">Started (Year):</td><td>".$show->started."</td></tr>"
."<tr><td class=\"jralign\">Ended (Year):</td><td>".$yearended."</td></tr>"
."<tr><td class=\"jralign\">Seasons:</td><td>".$show->seasons."</td></tr>"
."<tr><td class=\"jralign\">Classification:</td><td>".$show->classification."</td></tr>"
."<tr><td class=\"jralign\">Network:</td><td>".$show->network."</td></tr>"
."<tr><td class=\"jralign\">Status:</td><td>".$show->status."</td></tr>"
."</tfoot></table>"
."</table><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if what i did was the correct way, but it works.

All i did was change the `<tbody>` html tag inside the `<table>` to `<tfoot>` and updated my original javascript to look for the tfoot element instead and now only those tables collapse and not the others.

If anyone know if there will be issues in regards to this or cares to explain to me why this is, that would be excellent.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `getElementById`:

```
locl = document.getElementById("ctable").getElementsByTagName('tbody');
```

---

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), it would be

```
$('#ctable tbody').hide();
```

Comment: Hi SLaks, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried your code in the JS but it didn't seem to work. I have assigned the <tbody> to id=ctable and when i reload the pages the tables are now not auto collapsed, i can however manually collapse them.

Comment: @medoix: Did you read my code? It looks for `<tbody>` elements _inside_ an element named `ctable`.

Comment: yes i did read your code and have implemented as per edit above in original post. There is a '<tbody>' inside a '<table>' with the id="ctable"

Comment: and yes i have tried to change the '<table>' just before the '<tbody>' to '<table id=\"ctable\">'

Answer (score 1):

Typically IDs are unique to each element in a document.  (EDIT *should* be)

You can access an ID quickly with the famous "dollar function":

```
function $(idString) { return document.getElementById(idString); }
```

...which will return the element with that ID, e.g. `var targetTable = $('ctable');` and you can go to work on it.

---

The `name` attribute can be used to group elements together. You can then use `getElementsByName()` to get the group (except in IE).  Also, the `name` attribute is not strictly valid for most elements, so it's not really encouraged to use that.

However, I find that method quite useful anyway. This function will work in all browsers:

```
function $N(name,parentObj) {  //Can provide parent object to optimize search
  var ALL, E = new Array();
  parentObj ? ALL = $T("*",parentObj) : ALL = $T("*");

  for(a=0;a<ALL.length;a++) { 
   ALL[a].getAttribute('name') == name ? E.push(ALL[a]) : null; 
  }
  return E;
};
```

...which will return a group of elements with the same name.

---

Since we're on the subject, a strictly valid method of collecting a group of elements is having a common value in their `class` attribute.

The JQuery library has various functions that do all of this.

Comment: @Phrogz - Ahhh, but they don't HAVE to be.  :)  The page just works more predictably if they are.  If there are multiple IDs, `document.getElementById()` will just return the first or last ID found.

Comment: @Steve Yes, a person may choose serve any random crap over the wire and lie to the browser, calling it "text/html". Existentially, you are right: the universe and users will continue to exist if someone makes a syntactically invalid page. However, I was using the word "must" per [RFC 2119](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2119.html) with respect to the HTML standards. If we are talking about a valid page, then each `id` attribute _must_ be unique. :)

Comment: @Phrogz - My answer frequently refers to the strict validity of the page.  I'm not arguing standards here, or whether it's right, or wrong, I'm saying that it can be done in the current webdev environment without any errors thrown.  Personally, I think they must be unique also, but the page will also work if they are not.  Incidentally, for a person learning javascript, this information could be quite helpful, regardless of whether it's crap or not.

Comment: @Steve I think it's a disservice to suggest invalid code that happens to work currently, especially for new users. However, you are (of course) entitled to your opinion; I'm neither downvoting nor editing your answer. :) Just expressing for discussion a slightly different point of view.

Comment: @Phrogz - Fair enough. Not to needle, but from a debugging perspective, this information could provide a "oh, THAT's why this is happening" moment.  And yes, it is a travesty that this is allowed at all.  :)  Welcome to the world of webdev, heh heh heh.

Comment: @Steve I am unneedled. It's my opinion that telling users what is allowed and what is not—black & white—is more likely to provide that "ah-ha" moment. And no need to welcome me. I've been developing in earnest since ’95. :)

Comment: @Phrogz - Several problems I've run into in several languages I've dabbled in come precisely from the problem of people not stating what could happen which cost me time to dig up the error.  Multiple IDs could cause a situation like this - no error thrown, but the code isn't working properly. (also wasn't welcoming you personally, it was rhetorical[?], like "welcome to the jungle".)

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, however i still am at a loss as to what to do.. If there is an alternative way to do this by either searching for a specific class or another unique name how would i do it? and how would it be done in the code posted above. (I did not write the code from scratch). Or maybe there is an example on the internet somewhere? This example i am using was one simple html page so i assume there was no consideration to other pages using tables.

Answer (score 0):

To make the HTML valid, you are allowed to use every ID exactly *once*.

If you're able to assign the same (CSS) class to the tables that you want to hide (and it *should* be possible), you can use the class selector of your favourite javascript framework (example: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Comment: My ID's are unique as they are assigned while in a foreach loop using PHP. Hence why i cannot select the ID of the '<tbody>' because i do now know what they are going to be each time.